# Emacs like narrow to region

Tags: vimrc

Is it possible to narrow the text to a region, or function, and widen it as needed, as is possible in emacs via `narrow-to-region` ?

Comment: You may be interested in the [NrrwRgn](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn) plugin.

Comment: There are also alternatives to NrrwRgn mentioned here: https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn#similar-work. According to https://vimawesome.com/?q=narrow most stars and user has NrrwRgn which additionally lists https://github.com/PeterRincker/vim-narrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you hotsche for user938271 for guiding me in the right direction.

NarrwRgn is the plugin that did the trick for me. It's very simple to use: https://vimawesome.com/plugin/nrrwrgn .